# How secure is the ubuntuone nightlies repos?

Tags: ubuntu-one

For my computers with Natty UbuntuOne only works more or less stable with the nightlies releases ( https://launchpad.net/~ubuntuone/+archive/nightlies ). My main concern is, when I add the repo to my apt sources I get prompted with a warning that says that the key is not trustworthy. Now, how serious is this? I'm syncing tons of personal data - so I wonder whether I can trust nightlies or whether I should not use it?
Any idea? How big is the chance that my data are being read by a third party?

Answer (score 1):

Any nightly repository is likely to come with some risk of breakage (code wise), but as for your data - no one is reading it if you are using the same service as what you would use with the stock Ubuntu One.

The reason you are getting an error in Apt is because you did not [add](https://launchpad.net/+help/soyuz/ppa-sources-list.html) the gpg key for the repository (which I suggest you do, but it's not a huge deal).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
I used sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuone/nightlies
I thought that the key would be added when using add-apt-repository command?

Comment: @Philippe: it normally is, but sometimes it does not happen automatically. Just add the key manually to your software sources and you should be fine.